# Unable to install c++ compiler in eclipse mars ide

Tags: c++, eclipse-mars

In eclipse, even though I went to Help->Install New Software->http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars->Programming Languages->and I select all c++ related package options. Once all the packages are install , eclipse has to restart. Once I reopen eclipse, I go to New->File->Other->C/C++->Source File. When I click on Source File I get this error:

> The selected wizard could not be started.
>   Plug-in org.eclipse.cdt.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.cdt.ui.wizards.NewSourceFileCreationWizard.
>   An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.cdt.ui (826).

Comment: May be quicker to move your current Eclipse off to a new folder, reinstall and only install the tools you know you need. Add more as you discover you need it. At the very least, you will find the bad actor when you install it and it breaks the IDE. Or maybe you won't because it only breaks if installed in a particular order. Who can say?

Comment: No one has run into this issue before?